# HAL_SPI_Transmit works faster than direct registers manipulation, how come?

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, spi, hal

So knowing the fact that HAL is considered "slow" I decided to rewrtite a small routine in my programm using direct register access. And I decided to see, what I have won. Surprisingly, I actually lost.

So the code is

```
this->chip_select();
HAL_SPI_Transmit(hspi, spi_array, 3, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
this->chip_deselect();

this->chip_select();
SPI1->DR = spi_array[0];
while (!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
SPI1->DR = spi_array[1];
while (!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
SPI1->DR = spi_array[2];
while(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);
this->chip_deselect();
```

So first I send 3 bytes using HAL, and then the same 3 bytes using the registers and same SPI.

Using HAL, the "interbyte" pause is 0,848ms.
[image: Oscilloscope using HAL]

And using registers - 1.192ms [image: OSC using registers]

How come? Isn't doing things with registers supposed to be quicker?

P.S. The stm32 is l071, 32 Mhz, SPI is 16Mhz.

Comment: Have you checked the assembly code? What optimization are you using?

Comment: I'm at it right now, I see that while takes more assembly lines, Just don't know how to fix it. I'm at Debug build, so no omptimization.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so my mistake is - this was done on Debug build with 0 optimisation. With optimisation the register method is faster. Question is how to see the assembly code in Eclipse.

Comment: I think you have to start a debug session. Then the assembly code is displayed. If you have a Segger debugger, you can also try Ozone.